# Neutralize the smell of alcohol in liquid chalk

Tags: alcohols, smell

i'm trying to mix my own liquid chalk, which is a simple mixture of chalk and a high percentage alcohol in a ~2 part chalk 1 part alcohol relation.
Unfortunately the smell is rather intensive and I would like to find a way to neutralize or cover it up. 
Any suggestions?

I do not have a chemical backround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chemically, chalk is CaCO3. But blackboard chalk is mostly CaSO4.2H2O. If you want to mark something, the aim is to lay a coating of a certain (dry) thickness so as to be visible.

One way to reduce the odor is to reduce the amount of alcohol used by 1) making the paste richer in the chalk by a) just adding more chalk (but that might increase the viscosity too much), so b) grind the paste with a mortar and pestle (this may thin out the paste by causing a better variation in particle size and packing), or c) add some of whichever "chalk" you are not using (i.e., if you are using CaCO3, add some blackboard chalk and grind).

Or, 2) dilute the alcohol with a little water. You probably use alcohol to get a fast dry time, so may not be able to use much water. There are other solvents that have less odor (like heptane), but have other objections. Isopropanol has a higher boiling point (less odor, slower drying, but not much slower) than ethanol (but you are probably not using ethanol).

Or, 3) add a little TiO2. This will dramatically increase the visibility of thinner films, allowing application of much less paste and reducing the amount of alcohol exposure.

Or, 4) add a dispersant to reduce viscosity. Assuming you do not have access to many chemicals, I would suggest a little trisodium phosphate. Or a tiny amount of dishwashing detergent (be careful not to stir too vigorously so as to incorporate air bubbles); this may help wet particles or displace tiny air in pockets between particles. Then you can add more solid.

5) Chemical "masks" are available that claim to cover up obnoxious odors. In my experience they do not cover, but only add extra odor. But adding some delightful fragrance could distract from the alcohol odor to a more pleasing experience. Commercial additives I have used are coconut and cherry - both quite nice. You don't need much. Some food flavorings have enough odor to be useful here. Some people find acetone to be more pleasant than alcohol - a little acetone could change the odor to be more acceptable.

6) Slowing the evaporation by adding wax or high molecular weight alcohols (octadecanol) might reduce the odor while extending the dry time, if that is acceptable. Octadecanol is used to reduce the evaporation rate of water, and may work with alcohol; wax is often used with solvents.

Other than that, I can't think of anything.

Comment: Im using it to dry the skin on my hands for rock climbing. It sticks well and as far as i know leaves fewer traces than just dry chalk or Magnesia. So I'll try Option1, 4 and 5. Thanks!

Comment: Aaakkk! Na3PO4 is pretty alkaline, might dry your skin too much. Washing soda (sodium carbonate) is less alkaline, but would still be a skin dryer. Surfactant residue might become slippery if your hands sweat. Have you tried rosin like ball players use? Why not a paste of water and chalk - then wave your hands around a bit?